# How do I add an x-axis label to all plots in facet wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to repeat the x-axis label on every graph following facet_wrap in ggplot2?

For example, with this graph:

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=Exposure, y=OR, ymin=LCI, ymax=UCI)) + 
  geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) +
  geom_point(stroke = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~Outcome, nrow=2,scales="free")

p <- p + theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),text = element_text(size=13.1))
```

[image]
Using this data:

```
structure(list(Exposure = c("Insulin", "Insulin", "Insulin"), 
    Outcome = c("Cancer1", "Cancer2", "Cancer3"), OR = 3:5, LCI = c(2.8, 
    3.8, 4.8), UCI = c(3.2, 4.2, 5.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Can I make the "OR" appear under every plot, like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need separate panels with their own axis labels, why not make different plots, and put them together using `ggpubr::ggarrange`? In that case, every plot would also get an own y axis label.

I feel that this approach goes a bit against the philosophy of `ggplot2`, where there is always *one* legend for every mapped variable in principle. In that context, axis labels are just the legend names for the x and y variables.

But here I don't see a big issue with having repeated axis labels, you can quickly see that the same variable is mapped to each x axis.

Note that I used `scale_y_continuous(limits = c())` to make sure that all plot panels become comparable. If you use `facet_wrap()` on the 3 Outcomes in one facetted ggplot, the default (and sensible) behaviour is `facet_wrap(~Outcome, nrow = 2, scales = "fixed")`.

```
library(ggpubr) # also loads ggplot2
dat <- structure(list(Exposure = c("Insulin", "Insulin", "Insulin"), 
               Outcome = c("Cancer1", "Cancer2", "Cancer3"),
               OR = 3:5,
               LCI = c(2.8,3.8, 4.8),
               UCI = c(3.2, 4.2, 5.2)),
               class = "data.frame",
               row.names = c(NA,-3L))


for (i in dat$Outcome) {
  p <- ggplot(subset(dat, Outcome == i), aes(x=Exposure, y=OR, ymin=LCI, ymax=UCI)) + 
    geom_linerange(position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) +
    geom_point(stroke = 0.5,position=position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1,5.5)) + # use the same scales for all plots
    coord_flip() +
    facet_wrap(~Outcome, nrow=2) +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),text = element_text(size=13.1))
  
  assign(paste0("p",i), p)
  
}

ggpubr::ggarrange(pCancer1,pCancer2,pCancer3)
```

[image]